# Create ECS Context with Docker without Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create an ECS context using Docker so that I can deploy to AWS using the Docker Compose CLI

```
docker context create ecs <my context name>
```

But am receiving the following error:

```
"docker context create" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker context create --help'.

Usage:  docker context create [OPTIONS] CONTEXT

Create a context
```

I've edited my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to include

```
{
    "experimental": true
}
```

My Docker Compose CLI is version `2.14.2` and both the Client and Server show experimental as `true`

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.22
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.4
 Git commit:        3a2c30b63a
 Built:             Tue Dec 20 20:43:40 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.22
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.4
  Git commit:       42c8b31499
  Built:            Tue Dec 20 20:42:46 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.14
  GitCommit:        9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323.m
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d1
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

This should be available in Docker since `19.03`
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#install-the-docker-compose-cli-on-linux

So far I've only been able to create an ECS context by installing Docker with the experimental Arch package for Docker Desktop instead of Docker Compose Standalone. The weird thing is, Docker Desktop's Docker Compose version is only `2.13`.

This also might be related to this question:
[docker context create ecs myecs - requires exactly one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67236401/docker-context-create-ecs-myecs-requires-exactly-one-argument)